# Dissecting a complex type in C++ using the clang/llvm AST api

Tags: clang

Let's say I have a program with the following declaration:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> *> > s;
```

Now I would like to tokenize this, cut it in parts:

1. std vector
2. std vector
3. ```
    std vector pointer
   ```
4. ```
       std string
   ```

When going through the source-code, this example will give me a `VarDecl`. If I understood it correctly, this `VarDecl` contains the whole declaration. Now I think the next step is invoking `getType()` on that `VarDecl`. But then what? I expected a method that would return e.g. an iterator or so.

Below you'll see what I have. This works fine for e.g. "`int i`" or "`const char *const i = NULL;`" even for "`const std::string l = "12";`" but "`std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> *> > s;`" results in an "`int`"?(!?).

```cpp
void dissectType(ASTContext *const Context, const QualType x)
{
        if (x.isNull())
                return;

        QualType type = x.getNonReferenceType();

        for(;!type.isNull();) {
                if (type.hasQualifiers()) {
                        Qualifiers q = type.getQualifiers();

                        if (q.hasConst())
                                printf("const ");

                        if (q.hasVolatile())
                                printf("volatile ");

                        if (q.hasRestrict())
                                printf("restrict ");
                }

                const Type *t = type.getTypePtr();

                if (!t) {
                        printf("null?\n");
                        break;
                }
                else if (t -> isPointerType())
                        printf("* ");
                else if (t -> isFundamentalType()) {
                        std::string curType = type.getUnqualifiedType().getAsString();

                        printf("%s\n", curType.c_str());

                        break; // should be last entry in this chain
                }

                type = type->getPointeeType();
        }
}
```